# Delay with Android NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, performance, navigation-drawer

I've followed Google's recommended implementation of the Navigation Drawer and now have an introductory Fragment and Map fragment that I transition between.  The drawer worked smoothly until I added ActionBarSherlock to my project.  Now, when the home (original fragment) is selected the menu is delayed closing and I get an annoying flash before the home fragment appears.

The fragment transaction is handled by:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction
      .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
      .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, null)
      .commit();
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please put your code in code blocks.